# Windos Azure Mobile Service: Executing a Insert Stored Procedure in the data trigger

Tags: stored-procedures, azure, azure-mobile-services

I need to call a stored procedure when the Insert Script trigger is called.
The idea is use the stored procedure to insert rows in 3 tables, including the original table.

I have the following tables
- cars
- makers
- models

the stored procedure receives the car's data, maker's name and model's name. The SP looks in the makers and models table and insert a new record if not found.

This is my script trigger code:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {     
var params = [item.name, item.year, item.maker_name, item.model];
var sql = "exec myCars.sp_insert_car ?, ?, ?, ?";
mssql.query(sql, params,
{
    success: function(results) {
        request.respond(statusCodes.OK,{ 
            results: results,
            count: 1
        });       
    }        
});
}
```

Because the sp_insert_car inserts a row in the cars table, the trigger is called again. The weird thing is that it is also called when a new maker or model is inserted.

Is there a way to disable the second time the trigger is called?

Also, the SP has an output parameter that returns the new car id. Is there a way to get this output parameter?

I appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to run the request.execute first to get the data into the original table.  Then in the success function run your stored procedure to add the data, if missing, to the other tables.  Something along the lines of...

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    request.execute({
        success: function() {
            var params = [item.name, item.year, item.maker_name, item.model];
            var sql = "myCars.sp_insert_car ?, ?, ?, ?";
            mssql.query(sql, params, {
                success: function(results) {
                    request.respond(statusCodes.OK,{ 
                        results: results,
                        count: 1
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This also lets you grab the id of the newly inserted row in the original table, item.id, for use as a passed-in parameter for the stored procedure if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
add this  line ...
```

var mssql=request.service.mssql;

above underline

mssql.query ("EXEC dbo.Sp_User_Authentication ?, ?",request.query.username,request.query.password)